# Is $Q_n(x)=\sigma_{n+1}(x)/\sigma_n(x)$ logarithmically convex on $\mathbf{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convexity, open-problems

In 1975 J. van de Lune considered the monotony properties of the canonical Riemann Upper and Lower sums for $\int_0^1 t^xdt$, with  $x>0$.
Writing $\sigma_n(x) := 1^x+2^x+\cdots+n^x$ these sums are
$$U_n:=U_n(x)=\sigma_n(x)/n^{x+1} \quad \text{and}\quad L_n:= L_n(x)=\sigma_{n-1}(x)/n^{x+1}.$$
He proved (by mathematical induction) that $U_n>U_{n+1}$ and $L_n<L_{n+1}$.

A later proof of $U_n>U_{n+1}$ was obtained by showing  that the function
$$h(x):= h_n(x)=(\sigma_{n+1}/\sigma_n(x))(n/(n+1))^x$$
is strictly decreasing on all of $\mathbf{R}$.
Soon afterwards he came  to realize that the monotonicity of $h(x)$ would be a consequence of the logarithmic convexity of $Q(x):=Q_n(x)=\sigma_{n+1}(x)/\sigma_n(x)$ on all of $\mathbf{R}$.
Various numerical tests on $Q(x)$ were performed, but no proof was found.

Another application: From the logarithmic convexity of $Q(x)$ one may also obtain a simple proof of a conjecture made by H. Alzer and A. A. Jagers:
$$f(x):=f_n(x)=\Bigl(\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}\sigma_{n+1}(x)}{\frac1n \sigma_n(x)}\Bigr)^{1/x}$$
is strictly increasing for $x>0$.

> Question: Is for every (fixed) integer $n\ge2$, the function
>   $$x\in\mathbf{R}\mapsto Q_n(x):=(1^x+2^x+\cdots+n^x+(n+1)^x)/(1^x+2^x+\cdots+n^x)$$
>   logarithmically convex on all of $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: @Suvrit Much of the work of van de Lune about his conjecture is described in the
CWI Report PNA - R0502, May 2005:


[J. van de Lune, H. J. J. te Riele, "On some conjectural inequalities and their consequences"](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/10943/10943D.pdf)

Comment: @Suvrit Related material can be found in the paper


S. Abramovich, J. Baric, M. Matic, J. Pecaric, "On van de Lune-Alzer's Inequality"
J. of Math. Inequalities, 1, (2007) 563-587.
<http://jmi.ele-math.com/01-47/On-Van-de-Lune-Alzer-s-inequality>

Comment: Hi, juan! It looks like I can prove that there exists (unfortunately, rather large) $X_0>0$ such that all $Q_n(x)$ are log-convex for $x\ge X_0$. Would you be interested in such result or you know that much yourself by now?

Comment: @fedja Yes I will be interested. I do not know this, I think Jan never mention this to me. I will ask him.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'll post my argument then. It will be a somewhat long story so I'll do it in a few stretches (I don't think I'll have a single continuous time interval to make the full post, so I apologize for bumping it to the front page a few times when editing to add the stuff).

First of all, let us compute the second derivative of the logarithm of $\sigma_n(x)$. It is
$$
\frac{\sigma_n''(x)}{\sigma_n(x)}-\left[\frac{\sigma_n'(x)}{\sigma_n(x)}\right]^2=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^x\log^2 k}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^x}-
\left[\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^x\log k}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^x}\right]^2
\\
=\frac 12\frac{\sum_{k,m=1}^n k^xm^x(\log k-\log m)^2}{\sum_{k,m=1}^n k^xm^x}
\\
=\frac 12\frac{\sum_{k,m:1\le k<m\le n} k^xm^x \log^2 \frac km}{\sum_{k,m:1\le k<m\le n} k^xm^x+\frac 12\sum_{m:1\le m\le n} m^xm^x}
\\
=\frac 12\frac{\sum_{m=1}^n m^x\left(\sum_{k:1\le k<m} k^x \log^2 \frac km\right)}{\sum_{m=1}^nm^x\left(\sum_{k:1\le k<m} k^x+\frac 12 m^x\right)}
=
\frac 12\frac{\sum_{m=1}^n w_mE_m}{\sum_{m=1}^n w_m}\,,
$$
where
$$
w_m=m^x\left(\sum_{k:1\le k<m} k^x+\frac 12 m^x\right),\ 
E_m=\frac{\sum_{k:1\le k<m} k^x \log^2 \frac km}{\sum_{k:1\le k<m} k^x+\frac 12 m^x}.
$$
Thus, to show that the second derivative of $\log\sigma_{n+1}(x)$ is at least as large as that of $\log\sigma_{n}(x)$, it is sufficient to show that $E_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence in $n$.

Dividing the numerator and the denominator in the definition of $E_n$ by $n^{x+1}$, we see that for $x>0$, $E_n$ is the ratio of the $n$-th *trapezoid* sums $T_ng$ and $T_nf$ of the functions $g(z)=z^x\log^2z$ and $f(z)=z^x$ on $[0,1]$. It will be convenient from now on to use $p$ instead of $x$, so that $x$ could be used for something else as needed.

The trapezoid sum of a reasonably smooth on $[0,1]$ function $h$ can be also expressed as
$$
T_n h=\sum_{m:n\mid m}\widehat h(m)\,.
$$
If, in addition, $h$ is real-valued, then we can take the real part of both sides and get
$$
T_n h=\widehat h(0)+2\sum_{m:m>0, n\mid m}\Re\widehat h(m)\,,
$$
so, if the real parts of the Fourier coefficients $\widehat h(n)$ with positive indices have certain monotonicity for $n\ge n_0$, the trapezoid sums $T_nh$ will be monotone in the same way for $n\ge n_0$ (note that the direction of the monotonicity of the real parts of the Fourier coefficients of $h$ determines their signs as well since they tend to $0$ at infinity).

It has been shown in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379711/on-a-monotonicity-property-of-fourier-coefficients-of-truncated-power-functions) that for $p>1$, the real parts of the Fourier coefficients of $f(z)$ are decreasing all the way from $n=1$ to $n=\infty$, so for $p>1$ the denominators $T_nf$ of $E_n$ form a positive *decreasing* sequence (for $p\ge 2$ one can also give an elementary real variable proof of this fact). Thus, everything will be fine if we show that the numerators $T_ng$ form an *increasing* sequence.

That is not always true (and, technically, we do not need that much to show that $E_n$ increase, which seems to be a correct statement for all $p>0$) but the numeric experiments indicate that it is, indeed, so for $p\ge 4$ and we will (try to) prove that it is true for $p\ge p_0$ with some large $p_0>0$.

We shall start with the trivial reason that forces $T_ng$ to increase. Suppose that $g$ is *convex* on $[0,\frac n{n+1}]$. Then, using the representation
$$
\frac kn=\frac{n-k}{n}\frac k{n+1}+
\frac{k}{n}\frac {k+1}{n+1}
$$
for $k=1,\dots,n-1$, we get
$$
g(\tfrac kn)\le \tfrac{n-k}{n}g(\tfrac k{n+1})+
\tfrac{k}{n}g(\tfrac {k+1}{n+1})\,,
$$
so
$$
T_ng=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}g(\tfrac kn)\le
\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}[\tfrac{n-k}{n}g(\tfrac k{n+1})+
\tfrac{k}{n}g(\tfrac {k+1}{n+1})]
\\
=\frac{n-1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n g(\tfrac k{n+1})=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}T_{n+1}g\le T_{n+1}g\,.
$$
Let's now find the range of $z\in[0,1]$ for which $g''(z)>0$. We have $g'(z)=z^{p-1}(p\log^2 z+2\log z)$ and $g''(z)=z^{p-2}[p(p-1)\log^2 z+(4p-2)\log z+2]$. The expression in parentheses is positive at $0$ if $p>1$ and hits $0$ when
$$
\log z=-\frac{(2p-1)+\sqrt{2p^2-2p+1}}{p(p-1)}\approx -\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{p}
$$
for large $p>1$. Thus, for every fixed $\delta>0$, the convexity assumption holds as long as $\frac pn>2+\sqrt 2+\delta$ and $p>p(\delta)$.

We shall show that we have $\Re\widehat g(n+1)\ge \Re\widehat g(n)$ when $\frac pn<4-\delta$ and $p>p(\delta)$.

To this end we shall flip the function and write
$$
\Re\widehat g(n+1)-\Re\widehat g(n)=\int_0^1 e^{2\pi i nz}[e^{2\pi iz}-1](1-z)^p\log^2(1-z)\,dz=\int_0^1 G_{p,n}(z)\,dz\,.
$$
We shall do the contour integration again (like in [that thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379711/on-a-monotonicity-property-of-fourier-coefficients-of-truncated-power-functions) I mentioned already with an escape to $+i\infty$) but the details will be uglier.

First, let us take care of the return, which will again be done over the right side $1+iy$, $y\ge 0$ of the half-strip. We note that
$$
|G_{p,n}(1+iy)|=\left[\log^2 y+\left(\tfrac \pi 2\right)^2\right](1-e^{-2\pi y})y^p e^{-2\pi ny}\,.
$$
Recall that we are interested in $n>p/4$ and large $p$. Let us consider $|G_{1,1/4}(1+iy)|$. Choose $Y'>0$ so that $y\mapsto ye^{-\frac \pi 2y}$ is decreasing on $[Y',+\infty)$. Now choose $Y>0$ so that
$$
\int_{Y'}^Y|G_{1,1/4}(1+iy)|\,dy\ge \int_{Y}^{+\infty}|G_{1,1/4}(1+iy)|\,dy
$$
Then this inequality will be preserved if we multiply the integrand by any *decreasing* on $[Y',+\infty)$ function of $y$. In particular, we can multiply it by
$[ye^{-\frac \pi 2y}]^{p-1}e^{-2\pi(n-\frac p4)y}$ to get
$$
\int_{Y'}^Y|G_{p,n}(1+iy)|\,dy\ge \int_{Y}^{+\infty}|G_{p,n}(1+iy)|\,dy
$$
for all $p>1$, $n>\frac p4$. Thus the return integral will be at most
$$
2\int_{0}^Y|G_{p,n}(1+iy)|\,dy
$$
with some fixed $Y$ independent of $p$ and $n$ in our range.

Now we want to escape from $0$ to $+i \infty$ along some curvilinear contour. Note that $\left(\frac{\log(1-z)}z\right)^2$ and $\frac{e^{2\pi iz}-1}z$ are nice analytic functions with bounded argument in some fixed size neighborhood of our half-strip minus the disk of that size centered at $1$. Thus the argument of their product is some bounded (in the same neighborhood) harmonic function $U(z)$ with $U(0)=\frac \pi 2$, which then has bounded derivatives as well. Thus, the integral over the escaping contour is
$$
\int |G_{p,n}(z)|e^{i(-p\alpha+2\pi nx+U(z) +3\arg(z)+\theta)}|dz|=\int |G_{p,n}(z)|e^{i\Phi(z)}|dz|\,
$$
in the same notation as in the [thread about monotonicity of Fourier coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379711/on-a-monotonicity-property-of-fourier-coefficients-of-truncated-power-functions).

We shall choose below the phase $\Phi$ so that $\cos\Phi\ge c\sin\alpha$ with some absolute $c>0$. Let us show now that this will suffice.

Again, we shall compare $|G_{n,p}(z)|$ with $|G_{n,p}(z')|$ where $z'=1+i\Im z$ when $0\le \Im z\le Y$ and $z$ runs  over our contour. $|e^{2\pi i nz}|=|e^{2\pi i nz'}|$, $|e^{2\pi i z-1}|\ge |e^{2\pi i z'}-1|$, so these parts are fine.
Now $|1-z'|^p=|1-z|^{p}\frac{\Im z}{|1-z|}\sin^{p-1}\alpha$, so we have a huge gain here if $\alpha$ stays separated from $\frac\pi 2$, which will be true if $x$ stays away from $1$ (recall that $\Im z$ is bounded by $Y$ in that comparison). The problem is the $log$ factor.
In $|G_{p,n}(z)|$ we can guarantee just $\alpha^2$ (the square of the imaginary part) while in $|G_{p,n}(z')|$ we have $\log^2\Im z
+\left(\frac\pi 2\right)^2$. Fortunately, this expression times $\frac{\Im z}{|1-z|}$ stays bounded if we keep away from $1$ and below $Y$, so we see that to get $c\sin\alpha |G_{p,n}(z)|>2|G_{p,n}(z')|$, we just need to ensure that
$$
c\sin\alpha \alpha^2\ge C\sin^{p-1}\alpha\,,
$$
which, indeed, holds for large enough $p$ that depend on $c$, $Y$ and on how well we stay separated from $1$ in $x=\Re z$.

It remains to construct the contour.

To be continued...

Comment: Nice start, I wrote similar things but I do not recall to use Fourier coefficients here. Jan van de Lune is the real proponent of this problem, he asked me to propose it in MathOverflow. I have sent mails to him about your answer, but his health is not good and I have not received any answer until now. I am sure he will like it, his PhD-thesis is full of trapezoidal sums for $z^x$.

Comment: @ fedja Could you indicate how to obtain the monotonicity of the Fourier coefficients of $f$ when $p \geq 2$ with real variable methods?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Sure. You write the function $f_p(x)=(1-x)^p\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$ as a convex combination of $f_2(x/t)=t^{-2}(t-x)^2\chi_{[0,t]}(x)$, $t\in(0,1]$, after which you just show that $\frac h2+h\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_2(kh)$ (the "infinite" trapezoid sum starting at $0$ with step $h$) is increasing in $h>0$ by differentiation (this one has an explicit formula as long as you know that $nh<1<(n+1)h$; I believe that it is a bit easier to see counting the areas of small segments above the graph rather than expressing the whole sum directly but that should not really matter)..

Comment: I see, thank you. However it is not obvious to me, a priori, that the Fourier coefficients of $f_2(x/t)$ decrease...I did the computations by hands. Maybe you suggested the trapezoidal sums since you discovered that way, but I did not follow the hint. No way to extend the method to $p>1$? Positivity is clear by convexity but I do not see more.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I was not claiming that the Fourier coefficients of $f_2(x/t)$ decrease. Do they? What I did was exactly what I wrote (i.e., a computation by hand, just like yours). I do not see an immediate way to extend it to $p>1$ because there is no good explicit formula and the trapezoid sums of $f_1(x/t)$ are not monotone in general for $t\in(0,1)$ :-(

Comment: @ Many thanks, I misunderstood before and I thought it was a way to prove the monotonicity of the Fourier coefficients of $f_2(x/t)$. Actually they are decreasing and this gives, by your method, the monotonicity of the Fourier coefficeints of $f_p$ for $p >2$. I checked for $f_1(x/t)$ but this is no longer true.