# On a monotonicity property of Fourier coefficients of truncated power functions

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, fourier-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Is it true that
> $$a_{k,n}:=\int_0^{2\pi}x^k\cos(nx)\,dx$$
> is nonincreasing in natural $n$ for each $k\in\{0,1,\dots\}$?

This question is related to [this previous one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379678/when-are-fourier-coefficients-monotonic/379698#379698).

Twice integrating by parts, one obtains the recurrence
$$a_{k,n}= \frac k{n^2} (2\pi)^{k - 1} - \frac{k (k - 1)}{n^2}\,a_{k-2,n}$$
for $k\in\{2,3,\dots\}$, with $a_{0,n}=0=a_{1,n}$, which might be of use here.

We also have
$$a_{k,n}=\frac{(2 \pi )^{k+1}}{k+1}\;_1F_2\left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{k}{2}+\frac{3}{2};-n^2 \pi ^2\right).$$

Comment: Yes, they strictly decrease for every $k>1$ (not necessarily an integer). Now it is a bit too late here for posting but I'll do it in the morning. The trick is an appropriate contour integration, as usual ;-)

Comment: Just a thought, I haven't tried to see if it leads anywhere, but what happens if you write $x^k$ as a linear combination of the Bernoulli polynomials $B_i(x)$ for $0\le i\le k$. The $n$th Fourier coefficient of the $B_i(x)$ is some (positive) multiple of $n^{-i}$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman : Thank you for your comment. This seems to be another way to get the explicit expression for $a_{k,n}$ given in my answer. The main difficulty dealing with that expression (or in any other way with $a_{k,n}$) is that $a_{k,n}$ is oscillatory in real $n>0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer to write $2\pi$ in the exponent and reverse the direction of the monotonicity (none of which really matters, of course), so we shall fix $k>1$ (real in general), $n\in\mathbb Z_+$ (that is essential) and define
$$
a_n=\Re I_n, \qquad I_n=\int_0^1 (1-z)^ke^{2\pi in z}dz
$$
(I immediately write the integral in the complex notation; the branch of the $k$-th power is positive on $(0,1)$; all our paths will be in the upper half-strip $0\le x=\Re z\le 1, y=\Im z\ge 0$).

We want to show that $a_n>0$ and $a_{n+1}<a_n$. There is nothing to do for $n=0$, so from now on, we assume that $n\ge 1$.

Two (possibly overlapping) cases are possible: $k>4n$ and $k-1<4n$. We shall use different contours for these two cases.

*Case 1: $k>4n$*. Let $\rho=\frac {4n}{k}<1$. Consider the contour given by the equation $-k\alpha+2\pi n x=0$ (or, $x=\frac{2\alpha}{\pi\rho}$, $0\le\alpha\le\rho\frac{\pi} 2$) where the notation is clear from the following picture:

[image: Case 1 contour]

The explicit equation for the curve (using $\alpha$ as the parameter) is
$$
x=\frac{2\alpha}{\pi\rho},\quad y=\left(1-\frac{2\alpha}{\pi\rho}\right)\tan\alpha\,.
$$
Differentiating, we get $\dot x=\frac{2}{\pi\rho}$, $\dot y=\left(1-\frac{2\alpha}{\pi\rho}\right)\frac 1{\cos^2\alpha}-\frac{2}{\pi\rho}\tan\alpha$, so for the direction $\theta$ of $dz$, we get
$$
\tan\theta=\left(\frac{\pi\rho}2-\alpha\right)\frac 1{\cos^2\alpha}-\tan\alpha\,.
$$
At the very least, we see that $-\alpha\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}2$.

Now let $F_n(z)$ be the integrand in $I_n$. We have $F_{n+1}(z)=e^{2\pi iz}F_n(z)$, so $|F_{n+1}(z)|=e^{-2\pi y}|F_n(z)|<|F_n(z)|$
while $\arg F_{n+1}(z)=\arg F_{n}(z)+2\pi x=\arg F_{n}(z)+\frac{4\alpha}\rho$ on our contour. Note that $\arg F_{n}(z)=-k\alpha+2\pi n x=0$ on our contour, so we have
$$
a_n=\int |F_n|\cos\theta|dz|
$$
and
$$
a_{n+1}=\int |F_{n+1}|\cos(\theta+\tfrac {4\alpha}\rho)|dz|\,.
$$
Since $\cos\theta>0$ and $|F_{n+1}|<|F_{n}|$, all we need now is to show that
$$
\cos(\theta+\tfrac {4\alpha}\rho)\le \cos\theta
$$
If $-\alpha\le\theta\le 0$, we rotate by $\frac{4\alpha}\rho\in (4\alpha,2\pi)$, so we go beyond the symmetric angle $-\theta$ but stay short of the full revolution, so the inequality certainly holds. Now we need to consider $\theta>0$ only, in which case we want to show that we cannot rotate beyond $2\pi-\theta$, i.e., that $\theta+\frac{2\alpha}\rho\le\pi$ or
$$
\theta\le \pi-\beta, \beta=\frac{2\alpha}\rho\,. 
$$
Note that $0\le\beta<\pi$ and if $\beta\le\frac\pi 2$, then there is nothing to prove because $\theta\le\frac\pi 2$.

So, assume $\beta>\frac \pi 2$. Then we need $\tan\theta\le\tan(\pi-\beta)$, i.e. (rewriting $\alpha$ in terms of $\beta$),
$$
-\tan(\tfrac\rho 2\beta)+\frac\rho 2(\pi-\beta)\frac 1{\cos^2\tfrac\rho 2\beta}\le\tan(\pi-\beta).
$$
Bringing the terms on the left hand side to the common denominator, we get
$$
LHS=\frac{\rho (\pi-\beta)-\sin(\rho\beta)}{2\cos^2\tfrac\rho 2\beta}\le
\rho \frac{(\pi-\beta)-\sin(\beta)}{2\cos^2\tfrac 1 2\beta}
\\
\le
\frac{(\pi-\beta)-\sin(\beta)}{1+\cos\beta}=
\frac{(\pi-\beta)-\sin(\pi-\beta)}{1-\cos(\pi-\beta)}
$$
because $\rho<1$, $\sin(\rho\beta)\ge \rho\sin\beta$ and $\cos \tfrac\rho 2\beta\ge \cos \tfrac 1 2\beta$.

Let now $\tau=\pi-\beta\in(0,\frac\pi 2)$. Our inequality becomes
$$
\frac{\tau-\sin\tau}{1-\cos\tau}\le\frac{\sin\tau}{\cos\tau}\,,
$$
that is
$$
\tau\cos\tau\le\sin\tau\,,
$$
which is classical.

This finishes Case 1.

*Case 2: $k-1<4n$*. This case is way more interesting. We will not be able here to join $0$ to $1$ directly and will make a detour via $+i\infty$. In this case we define $\rho=\frac{4n}{k-1}>1$ and use the same equation but with $0\le\alpha<\frac \pi 2$. Even as $\alpha\to\frac\pi 2-$, we shall have only $x\to \frac 1\rho<1$ while $y\to+\infty$ with the picture like this:

[image: Case 2 contour]

Of course, once we escape to $+i\infty$, we have to come back from it, which we  will do over the right boundary line $z=1+it$ of the strip. That the abscissa of the escape is different from that of the return is not a problem because $F_n,F_{n+1}$ decay to $0$ when we go up, so we may think that we join the paths high up by a horizontal interval and then take the limit.

We still have $\theta<\frac\pi 2$. I claim that now $\theta>0$. Indeed, $\tan\theta$ is given by the same formula (only now $\rho>1$!), so we have
$$
\tan\theta=\left(\frac{\pi\rho}2-\alpha\right)\frac 1{\cos^2\alpha}-\tan\alpha\ge \left(\frac{\pi}2-\alpha\right)\frac 1{\cos^2\alpha}-\tan\alpha
\\
=\frac{(\pi-2\alpha)-\sin(2\alpha)}{2\cos^2\alpha}
=\frac{(\pi-2\alpha)-\sin(\pi-2\alpha)}{2\cos^2\alpha}>0\,.
$$
Note that now the argument regime of $F_n(z)dz$ is $\theta-\alpha$ because $-(k-1)\alpha$ cancels with $2\pi nx$. Thus, on the way up, we have
$$
\int |F_n(z)|\cos(\theta-\alpha)|dz|
$$
we look at the way down now matching to $z$ the point $z'=1+i\Im z$ (which is a legitimate parameterization). Notice that $|F_n(z')|=\sin^k\alpha|F_n(z)|$ and the argument of $F_n(z')dz'$ is constant and does not depend on $n$ (only the power factor matters) and $|dz'|=\sin\theta|dz|$. Thus, if we combine both paths, we shall get
$$
\int_{\text{upward path}} |F_n(z)|[\cos(\theta-\alpha)-\lambda\sin\theta\sin^k\alpha]|dz|
$$
where $\lambda\in[-1,1]$ is some constant (common for $n$ and $n+1$).
The key point now is that
$$
\cos(\theta-\alpha)=\cos\theta\cos\alpha+\sin\theta\sin\alpha
\ge\sin\theta\sin\alpha\ge |\lambda\sin\theta\sin^k\alpha|
$$
so the factor is, again, positive.

For $F_{n+1}$, we get
$$
\int_{\text{upward path}} |F_{n+1}(z)|[\cos(\theta-\alpha+\tfrac{4\alpha}{\rho})-\lambda\sin\theta\sin^k\alpha]|dz|
$$
again, and we see that everything boils down to the inequality
$$
\cos(\theta-\alpha+\tfrac{4\alpha}{\rho})\le\cos(\theta-\alpha)\,.
$$

If $\theta-\alpha>0$, then it is $\le\frac{\pi} 2-\alpha$ and the rotation is by at most $4\alpha\le 2\alpha+\pi$, so we get short of $\frac{3\pi}2+\alpha$, where we could have any chance to bring the cosine up again. Thus, we need to consider only the case $\theta-\alpha<0$. If $\rho\le 2$, then our rotation is by at least $2\alpha$ and at most $2\pi$, which diminishes the cosine of any angle between $-\alpha$ and $0$. Finally, if $\rho>2$, then we shall just show that we necessarily have $\theta>\alpha$ (the case we have considered already). Indeed, comparing the tangents, we see that we need just to prove the inequality
$$
\left(\frac{\pi\rho}2-\alpha\right)\frac 1{\cos^2\alpha}\ge 2\tan\alpha\,.
$$
Since $\rho>2$, that reduces to
$$
\pi-\alpha>\frac\pi 2>1\ge \sin(2\alpha)
$$
and the story is over.

The admissible contours are not unique, but the leeway in choosing them is rather small. I just posted the most elegant ones I could find. I hope it is all correct, but feel free to ask questions if something looks fishy or is just unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From  $\rho=\frac n{4k}$ and $-k\alpha+2\pi n x=0$, I am getting $x=\frac{\alpha}{8\pi\rho}$, rather than $x=\frac{2\alpha}{\pi\rho}$. Hopefully, this does not matter. Could you please check this?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm an idiot, of course: $\rho$ is defined from the equivalence $x=\frac{2a}{\pi\rho}\Longleftrightarrow -k\alpha+2\pi nx=0$, so $\rho=\frac{4n}{k}$ (or $\frac{4n}{k-1}$) and the cases are $\rho<1$ and $\rho>1$. Just screwed up elementary division and put $4$ in a wrong place. All it changes is the case splitting point. I'll edit :-)

Comment: Sounds great! I am looking forward to reading your solution after the edits.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I've edited already: the only edit required was to move $4$ from top to bottom and from bottom to top in $4$ places (sory for the pun :-) )

Comment: Great, I will read it after getting some sleep. :-)

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you! I have just taken the liberty to fix one typo.

Comment: @IosifPinelis If you like such stuff, I want to attract your attention to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107534/is-q-nx-sigma-n1x-sigma-nx-logarithmically-convex-on-mathbfr. On $[1,+\infty)$ it boils down to showing that the Riemann sums of $x^k\log^2 x$ are increasing in $n$, i.e., that the real parrts of the integrals $J_n=\int_0^1 z^k\log^2 z\frac{e^{2\pi i n z}}{1-e^{2\pi i n z}}dz$ are negative and go down in absolute value. I strongly suspect it can be done in a similar way but the details escape me :-(

Comment: Thank you for this link. I will have it in mind. I once had a somewhat similar contour integration idea, which was then referred to as "a non-asymptotic version of the
so-called stationary-phase method" -- https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00120 or https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11785-018-0765-x . However, there the choice of the contour was more straightforward.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that there is a mistake in the proof. Indeed, the proof does not seem to use the condition that $n$ is an integer. On the other hand, $a_{k,n}$ is oscillatory and sign-changing in real  $n>0$. Taking now the negative value of $a_{k,n}$ at a local minimum (say $n_*$) in real $n>0$ and comparing it with a near-$0$ value of $a_{k,n}$ at $n$ near $\infty$, we see that it is impossible for $a_{k,n}$ to be decreasing in $n\in\{n_*,n_*+1,\ldots\}$.

Comment: The two places in the proof where I think a mistake was made are where it is stated that the inequalities of the form  $|F_{n+1}|<|F_{n}|$ and $\cos s\le\cos t$ imply $|F_{n+1}|\cos s\le|F_{n}|\cos t$. Such a conclusion will not hold if e.g. $\cos s=\cos t<0$. I hope there is a way to save this proof, maybe by making (say in Case 1) $-k\alpha+2\pi n x+\theta$ (rather than $-k\alpha+2\pi n x$) constant.

Comment: @IosifPinelis There is no "negative value of $a_{k,n}$" *the way I defined it*. Notice that I flipped $x^k$ to put the maximum at the origin, so our definitions coincide only for an integer $n$! For real $n>0$ I, indeed, do claim that the sequence is decreasing along $n,n+1,\dots$ but for *my* integral, not for *yours*. $\cos t$ can never be negative; a part of the proof was devoted to that. Check everything again :-)

Comment: Keeping $-k\alpha+2\pi n x+\theta$ constant would make things more transparent, but then you'll get an unstable differential equation for the contour, which has to be solved backwards and then hitting $0$ at the end is a big headache. It is great that you are doing sanity checks on my argument but it is important to pay attention to various little details like that difference in definitions. Otherwise, indeed, everything falls apart :-)

Comment: I am relieved now, after the panic attack. :-) Now appreciate your proof even more -- there are even more subtle points there than I noticed previously!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the recurrence may indeed help, as it can be rewritten as
$$b_{k,n}= \frac{(2\pi)^{k - 1}n^{k-2}}{(k-1)!} - b_{k-2,n}$$
for
$$b_{k,n}:= \frac{a_{k,n}n^k}{k!},$$
which allows one to explicitly express $b_{k,n}$ and hence $a_{k,n}$ as a (finite) alternating sum:
$$a_{k,n}=k!\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor-1}\frac{(-1)^j(2\pi)^{k-2j-1}}{n^{2j+2}(k-2j-1)!}=\frac{k(2\pi)^{k-1}}{n^2}-\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)(2\pi)^{k-3}}{n^4}+\cdots.$$

Comment: Erm.. I see *eventual* monotonicity from it, all right, but how do you handle huge $k$ and relatively small $n$?

Comment: @fedja : Sorry, I did not intend to claim that the monotonicity is obvious from this.